# How to access List<T> items dring runtime? Where does this data go, and how can I use it? (I think this is a "fundamentals" thing)

Tags: unity, c#, unity-ui

So, I'm piecing together a nutrition-helper that's mostly a catalog, some lists, and a calculator.  I'm using Unity C#, an xml deserializer, and building to the android platform.

The xml deserializer builds 4 different lists from one file... no problem.

```
//https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nYWlB7HRNSE (thanks for this tutorial!)
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

[XmlRoot("GroceryCatalog")]  //refer to xml's collection name areound item arrays
public class TheGrocer
{
    [XmlArray("ItemLs")]
    [XmlArrayItem("ItemL")]
    public List<ItemL> ItemLs = new List<ItemL>();

    [XmlArray("ItemGs")]
    [XmlArrayItem("ItemG")]
    public List<ItemG> ItemGs = new List<ItemG>();

    [XmlArray("ItemHs")]
    [XmlArrayItem("ItemH")]
    public List<ItemH> ItemHs = new List<ItemH>();

    [XmlArray("ItemCs")]
    [XmlArrayItem("ItemC")]
    public List<ItemC> ItemCs = new List<ItemC>();

    public static TheGrocer Load(string path) //"path" is the the name of the XML file, it is provided by the script calling TheGrocer
    {
        TextAsset _xml = Resources.Load<TextAsset>(path);

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TheGrocer));

        StringReader reader = new StringReader(_xml.text);

        TheGrocer items = serializer.Deserialize(reader) as TheGrocer;

        reader.Close();
        return items;
     }
}
```

Each of those lists are accessed by item-type specific menu scripts, which build items out of the list, and adds buttons with references to the icons and stuff.

```
    //https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oba1k4wRy-0 (Thanks for the help!)
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class OurLeans : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]    private GameObject buttonTemplate;              ///Button Template
    [SerializeField]    private GridLayoutGroup contentLayoutGroup;     ///The Button Container, used to adjust column count, on the fly

    public const string path = "GroceryCatalogs/GroceryCatalog200304"; //specify XML file name

    private Color genericColor = new Color(0.6509804f, 0.3215686f, 0.1372549f, 1);

    private void Start()
    {
        TheGrocer grocer = TheGrocer.Load(path);  ///Read XML in List (An instance of a GreensMarket initiates a list)

        foreach (ItemL item in grocer.ItemLs)  ///Interprets XML item list into a GreenItem
        {
            ItemL newItem = new ItemL();
            newItem.itemID = item.itemID;
            newItem.itemDesc1 = item.itemDesc1;
            newItem.itemDesc2 = item.itemDesc2;
            newItem.itemDesc3 = item.itemDesc3;
            newItem.itemDesc4 = item.itemDesc4; //Leaness
            newItem.iconName = item.iconName;
            //newItem.iconBG   = item.iconBG;
            newItem.qTY1 = item.qTY1;
            newItem.uOM1 = item.uOM1;
            newItem.qTY2 = item.qTY2;
            newItem.uOM2 = item.uOM2;

            newItem.Text1 = item.itemDesc2;
            newItem.Text2 = item.qTY1.ToString() + " " + item.uOM1;
            newItem.Text3 = item.itemDesc4.ToString() + " Leaness";
            newItem.iconSprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Icons/Leans/" + newItem.iconName);

            AddGUIButton(newItem);
        }
    }

    void AddGUIButton(ItemL newItem)
    {
        GameObject newButton = Instantiate(buttonTemplate) as GameObject;
        newButton.SetActive(true);
        newButton.transform.SetParent(buttonTemplate.transform.parent, false);
        newButton.GetComponent<GroceryItemButtonScript200318>().SetIcon(newItem.iconSprite, genericColor);
        newButton.GetComponent<GroceryItemButtonScript200318>().SetText(newItem.Text1, newItem.Text2, newItem.Text3);
    }
}
```

This is the buttons' script, for reference:

```
   //https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oba1k4wRy-0 (The help is much appreciated!)
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GroceryItemButtonScript200318 : MonoBehaviour
{
    //[SerializeField] private TheGrocer myGrocer;
    [SerializeField] private Image myIcon;
    [SerializeField] private Image myIconBG;
    [SerializeField] private Text myName;
    [SerializeField] private Text myDescTop;
    [SerializeField] private Text myDescBottom;

    public void SetIcon(Sprite mySprite, Color myBGColor)
    {        
        myIcon.sprite = mySprite;
        myIconBG.color = myBGColor;        
    }

    public void SetText(string text1, string text2, string text3)
    {
        myName.text = text1;
        myDescTop.text = text2;
        myDescBottom.text = text3;        
    }

    public const string path = "GroceryCatalogs/GroceryCatalog200304"; //specify XML file name

    public void AddToPlate()
    {
        ///?       
    }
}
```

Now, people want to hit the button, and add the related item to their plate's  list.

So... I think I should be able to reference the lists the deserializer makes, but I'm not sure how to reach it when a button is clicked.

Should I:
A) Assign all the "newItem" information to the GUI Buttons so I can pass that info directly to the user's final list? 
  *Is this creating a lot of redundant memory?*

B) Assign minimal info to the GUI Buttons, and use the unique itemID strings to search for the rest of the info in grocer.ItemLs.
  *Is this burning a lot of resources searching for strings?*

c) Grab the item's index number in the list, assign that as a variable to the GUI Button, then it knows exactly what to recall when it's hit?
  *If this is the best route, how do I get the GUI button script to find the List?*

Thanks... and I appreciate folks helping me refine the question.

Comment: I would first off start by making some sensible names. All your stuff has really difficult-to-parse names. Making readable code makes it way easier for you and others to notice problems and understand what it doing on. Like ItemG is probably a GroceryItem. Also you have many lines of code that seem to duplicate an ItemG. Perhaps pull out a duplicate method or something like that.

Comment: Did you mean to save grocer to a member variable, so it survives after the end of the Start method?

Comment: How can I access the list grocer.ItemGs from another script, during runtime?  Is it like... grocer.itemGs (and the other 3 lists grocer class instance makes) is what's being read at start, so I should make GUI items with minimum info, and access those initial lists again if I need to read the rest of the item's details. Right? So, how do I get the new button seen above to retrieve info from grocer.itmGs? I mean, I made the lists at start, I can make buttons out of the.... how do I reference the list's items, and get specific info out?